# Correct terminology for optimization problem

Tags: terminology, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

An optimization problem aims to minimize the sum of a variable u over a time-series. It is made of three variables that are in a linear relationship. Two binary variables

$$x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$$

and

$$u_1, u_2, \dots u_n$$

and a continuous variable

$$y_1, y_2, \dots y_n$$

The objective function is
$$minimize \sum u$$

s.t.
$$y_{n}=y_{n-1}+ u_{n}\cdot C$$
$$y_{n}\geq x_{n} \cdot M$$
$$0<y_{n}<2\cdot M$$
$$x_{n}\wedge u_{n} \in \{0,1\}$$

Would "Binary linear programming problem" be the correct terminology to describe this?

Comment: You cannot combine "min" with a strict inequality constraint, since the feasible region is not closed. You should either use "inf" or non-strict inequality constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just to make sure I understand correctly. If I formalize the obj. function as $$min \sum_{t}^{t+7~days}$$ I can use "min"? 7 days is the duration of the optimized time-period.

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{i=t}^{t+7}$? If $t$ (the starting index of the summation) is fixed a priori (i.e., it does not depend on $x$, $y$ or $u$), and the terms in the sum are linear, then yes.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that maybe it wasn't clear that $min$ stands $minimize$ and not $minimum$ in this case! Sorry! Assuming $t$ is not fixed a priori, could I express this as $$minimize \sum_{t} u(t)$$?

Comment: What is $u(t)$?

Comment: the value of $u$ at time slot $t$

Comment: What is the exact formula?

Comment: It's defined by the discrete function
$$y(t)=y(t-1)+\frac{u(t)-y(t-1) \cdot a}{b}$$ where a and b are constants

Comment: We typically write $u_t$ and $y_t$ instead of $u(t)$ and $y(t)$. It seems like your condition is linear and that by renaming variables you can write your problem as $\min_x \{c^Tx : Ax \leq b\}$ with the restriction that some $x$ are integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct contemporary term is *mixed integer linear optimization*.